# How to replace a column with another column from another table?

Tags: python, sql, database, griddb

I have a database stored in a GridDB container. The main table in the database contains a column with outdated data. I would like to replace the whole column with a new column from another table (with the same total number of rows). Is there any way I could do that with Python?

For example, the whole process looks thus:

```sql
-- old table

column_0 | column_1 | old_column
------------+-----------+------------
1344 | Max | 5263.42525
1345 | John | 1465.41234
1346 | Alex | 8773.12344
1347 | Matthew | 5489.23522
1348 | Mark | 9874.31423


-- replacement

col_0 | updated
---------+------------
4242 | 3553.42824
4243 | 8942.98731
4244 | 1424.36742
4245 | 7642.75352
4246 | 2844.92468


-- output

column_0 | column_1 | old_column
------------+-----------+------------
1344 | Max | 3553.42824
1345 | John | 8942.98731
1346 | Alex | 1424.36742
1347 | Matthew | 7642.75352
1348 | Mark | 2844.92468
```

I have tried to replace the values one by one but I want something faster and kind of automated.

Comment: Why in the replacement data , the col_0 values are different?

Comment: What you're trying to do is a join, but we're missing an information here. What is the criterion which links rows together in different tables ? Just their ordered position ?

Comment: Try to add your code, even if it is a small snippet, do not use the community as a problem solver.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is what is called a join in SQL. Assuming that rows between tables are matched according to their rank, you can join two subqueries with an `rank()` window function and then pick the wanted columns from both sets.

```sql
SELECT column_0, column_1, updated AS old_column
FROM
    (SELECT rank() over() r, * FROM old_table ORDER BY column_0) left
    JOIN (SELECT rank() over() r, * FROM replacement ORDER BY col_0) right
    ON left.r = right.r
```

Each sub-queries will add a new counter for each row with the rank function, rows will be matched together according to that rank value producing a row containing columns from both sub-queries. The top level will then only pick the wanted column with an appropriate `AS` clause for the wanted naming.

Each subquery